# I am trying to put my prefix in a command i'm setting up

Tags: discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config/config.json')

module.exports = {
    name: 'musichelp',
    aliases: ['mhelp'],
    description: "Shows you all the music commands!",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord, cmd) {
        const musicEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setColor('#8c88fc')
        .setTitle("Music Help")
        .addField(
            {name: "Play Command!", value: `${config.prefix}`+ "play \n **Aliases** = 'p' \n\n ***Description*** \n The play command plays music in a voice channel (You need to be in a vc to be able to use this command!)", inline: true},
            {name: "Leave Command!", value: `${config.prefix}`+ "leave \n **Aliases** = 'dc', 'disconnect' \n The leave command leaves the current voice channel it's in (You need to be in a vc to be able to use this command)", inline: true},
        )

        .setFooter("It's recommended to set the volume of the bot to between 35 - 50!");

        await message.reply(musicEmbed);
    }
}
```

This is my code (i'm planning on putting a custom prefix system in my bot in the near future) im trying to get my prefix (that i have stored in a config folder thats been required) and then place it in an embed, any help would be greatly appreciated!  [image]:D

The img is the response i get back!

Comment: I think you're looking for `.addFields` not `.addField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add fields to your embed, you have 2 options, either `.addField` or `.addFields`.

**.addField**

```
.addField('Title 1', 'Description 1')
.addField('Title 2', 'Description 2')
```

**.addFields**

```
.addFields(
     { name: 'Title 1', 'Description 1' },
     { name: 'Title 2', 'Description 2' }
)
```

They both give the same result. The one you're looking fore is the second :D